# dictsort template filter and filtering with two columns

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In template for now I am using this:

```
{% for item in mydict|dictsortreversed:"column1" %}
```

But I have to sort data by two columns - is there any option in dictsort to do this?
Or any alternative to do this in template?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can see in the Django [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L486), there is no support for this.

However, since Python sorts in a [stable way](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts). This is trivial to implement by sorting twice :)

```
{% for item in mydict|dictsortreversed:"column1"|dictsortreversed:"column2" %}
```

Comment: Note: order the dictsort filters by ascending importance -- the last one will be the primary sort.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like -

```
{% for item in mydict|dictsortreversed %}
    {% if forloopcount|diviisbleby:"2" %}
            <td> item </td> 
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td> item </td>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Check out the [forloop counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and [divisible by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) template tags for more ideas.